# WPF RemoveHandler with a new handler

Tags: wpf, event-handling

I've seen this in many answers, and I can't figure out how it works.

It usually goes this way (pseudocode):

```
UIElement.AddHandler(routedEvent, new EventHandler(handler));
```

which basically *seems* to creates a new instance of a delegate and pass it so that it is added to a list of delegates. So far, so good.

But then, to remove it, you do:

```
UIElement.RemoveHandler(routedEvent, new EventHandler(handler));
```

Which just *seems* to remove a new instance, not the previous one.

What's going on, here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass a reference to a new `EventHandler` that you don't keep any reference to if you want to be able to remove it later on.

Cast the handler to the appropriate delegate type.

This works, i.e. the event handler is only invoked once when the `Button` is clicked:

**Code:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btn.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)OnClick);
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("click");
        btn.RemoveHandler(Button.ClickEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)OnClick);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Content="Button" />
```